# Text are coming first?

Tags: html, css, hover

> When I hover over the experience item, the texts appear instantly, and then the height increases gradually over one second. Why is this happening? I want my text to increase in height in sync with the height increase, without any delay. What can I do about this

```css
.experience-item {
  height: 285px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 1s ease-out;
  position: relative;
}

.experience-item .experi-details {
  padding: 20px;
}

.experience-item:hover {
   overflow: visible;
   height: 500px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 100px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="experience-item">
    <img src="../images/catering.jpg" alt="">
    <h3>Bondhu Ekota Caters</h3>
    <div class="experi-details">
    <p><span>Position:</span> Food Distributor</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `transition: height 1s ease-out;` to  `transition: all 1s ease-out;`, otherwise only the height is transitioned, everything else appears instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to this:-

```
.experience-item {
  height: 285px;
  overflow: hidden; /* Set overflow to hidden by default */
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: height 1s ease-out, overflow 1s ease-out; /* Include overflow in the transition */
  position: relative;
}
```

By adding this updated CSS code, both the height and overflow properties will transition over 1s.